# How can I verify text exist within a table using Selenium IDE?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

Using selenium IDE- 
I am looking for a way to locate and or verify a value in a table. There are more columns in the table, but I am only concerned with the first 4. Also the number of rows varies as well as the location of the value I am looking for.

So, say, I am looking for username there. the username = “fred”, who could exist in any row 1 to 10.
 How could I locate and verify that user exist?
[image]

Comment: Please post your HTML-Code as code not as image

Comment: yes actual code so we can copy and paste when makin our answers please

Answer (score 1):

Personally the best way I have found is to loop through the table rows, then get the text from the  you need to and compare. Below I have an example of what you can use, it should be easy enough to change to your liking.

```
public boolean searchUsername(WebDriver driver, String username){
    boolean isFound = false;
    List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody > tr"));
    for(WebElement row : rows){
        if(row.findElement(By.cssSelector("td:nth-of-type(2)").getText.equals(username){
            isFound = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is two different task in selenium IDE.

1. Create loop in selenium. Dig this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033321/how-to-loop-tests-in-selenium-ide/11061700#11061700)
2. Apply table data finding logic. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18110123/3251682) can help you

Answer (score 0):

Maybe do

```
assertText
table td(3).text
='fred'
```

Will look in all the column 3 values

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the tds of table.

You need to first capture the table id or the div under which table is located.
then using this element you have to loop through all td and check td's text == "fred".

Answer (score 0):

Verifytext can be used to verify text exist within the table.
[image]

[image]

[image]